# How do I simulate two variables in R which are non-linearly related?

Tags: r, simulation, nonlinear-functions

I've been lurking on SO for a while, but finally have a question to which I couldn't find an answer on this site or anywhere else. So account created, and here goes. Apologies if this question has indeed been answered elsewhere. My searching skills need improving then!

In R, I would like to generate two variables which are non-linearly related.

I've figured out how to use the mvrnorm function in the library MASS to simulate a linear association between two variables as below, but would now like to simulate two variables which follow a non-linear association.

```
library ('MASS')

data = mvrnorm(n=100, mu=c(170, 80), Sigma=matrix(c(1, 0.85, 0.85, 1),   nrow=2), empirical=TRUE)
height = data[, 1]  # standard normal (mu=170, sd=1)
weight = data[, 2]  # standard normal (mu=80, sd=1)
```

I don't particularly mind what kind of non-linear association it is (e.g. exponential, logarithmic etc). I merely would like to generate some scatterplots that demonstrate the difference between a linear and a non-linear association.

I am no statistics nor an R expert, so seemingly overly simplistic answers would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I think this simulates two variables with no association (i.e. with r = 0), rather than with a non-linear association (such as e.g. a logarithmic or an exponential association.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply IceCreamToucan. This creates two variables which are perfectly associated. But how do I create noise in the data as in the example I gave, where r was 0.85 (such as you might find when doing measurements in human participants)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a quick way is to create a non-linear variable, then add some noise to it:

```
x = seq(-100, 100)    # just a sequence of numbers
y = x^2 + rnorm(length(x), 0, 1000)      # generate non-linear association + noise
plot(x, y)
```

[image]

If some function is not clear, please let me know.

PS: No need to apologize. If nobody ever asked rookie questions, there would be no experts in the world.

Comment: Thanks Leevo! This will work for my purpose of demonstrating non-linearity. Your answer made me realise though I should have phrased my question more carefully. In your solution, there is only one y-value (.e.g. weight) for every x-value (e.g. height), I think? In a sample of humam participants, I might have several persons with the same height (i.e. x-value). If I wanted to simulate that, would I be better off using runif instead of seq?

Comment: You're welcome. There are so many ways to add multiple observations with the same x. e.g. you can add additional y distributions to the already existing one.

    `x = seq(-200, 200)    # just a sequence of numbers
    y1 = x^2 + rnorm(length(x), 0, 1000)      # generate non-linear associations + noise
    y2 = x^2 + rnorm(length(x), 0, 3000)
    y3 = x^2 + rnorm(length(x), 0, 6000)
    
    plot(x, y1)
    points(x, y2)   # adds other points to the last plot
    points(x, y3)`

Someone might argue it's not the most elegant solution, but it's definitely quick and easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

`mvrnorm::MASS` doesn't allow you to vectorize the means in this dimension, but you can do it by adding suitable offsets to the mean values.

```
set.seed(101)
dd <- MASS::mvrnorm(n=100, 
     mu=c(0,0), Sigma=0.001*matrix(c(1, 0.85, 0.85, 1),   nrow=2),
         empirical=TRUE)
xvec <- seq(0,2,length=100)
dd[,1] <- dd[,1] + exp(-3*xvec)
dd[,2] <- dd[,2] + xvec
plot(dd[,1],dd[,2])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ben! This does indeed produce the graph, but I'm afraid I don't understand all of the code. Why do you multiply the covariance matrix with 0.001? (I have to admit I don't quite understand how mvrnorm works, despite reading on it).

Comment: I made the variance much smaller so the nonlinear pattern could be seen.